# How to rewrite links with Cyrillic in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am currently trying to make my website more seo friendly throught .htaccess. So here's the deal:

I have a php book.php?book_title=нещо на кирилица

So obviously the string after book_title I will be using is in cyrilic, so I want whenever I open www.domain.com/книга/нещо на кирилица to be seen as if it was book.php?book_title=нещо на кирилица.

Comment: you can't use spaces in a url... you would need to generate a "slug" type thing like `www.domain.com/книга/нещо-на-кирилица` then is piece of cake in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work in your case

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^книга/(.*)$ book.php?book_title=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Maybe some errors occur in the encoding? It says this: 


Not Found

The requested URL /ÐºÐ½Ð¸Ð³Ð°/ÐšÐ°Ðº Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÐ³Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€Ñ Ñ‚Ñ€ÑŠÐ¼Ð¿ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: is you .htaccess file using utf-8 ?

Comment: No, I am not sure how to do that.